# Regex for special ucwords

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to do an `ucwords()` in JavaScript on a string of the form: test1_test2_test3 and it should return Test1_Test2_Test3.

I already found an `ucwords` function on SO, but it only takes space as new word delimiters. Here is the function:

```
function ucwords(str) {
return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
});
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an underscore to the list of acceptable word breaks:

```
function ucwords(str) {
return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|[\s_]+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
})
};
```

As you can see ive replace the bit which was `\s+` to `[\s_]+`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bs8ZG/

Answer (score 2):

Try the regular expression

```
/(?:\b|_)([a-z])/
```

For an example see [here](http://ideone.com/gJ5md)

Answer (score 0):

Two other solutions that seems pretty complete:

```
String.prototype.ucwords = function() {
    str = this.toLowerCase();
    return str.replace(/(^([a-zA-Z\p{M}]))|([ -][a-zA-Z\p{M}])/g,
        function($1){
            return $1.toUpperCase();
        });
}
$('#someDIV').ucwords();
```

Source: http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/ucwords-javascript/

```
function ucwords (str) {
  return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function ($1) {
    return $1.toUpperCase();
  });
}

ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
```

Source: http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/

Worked fine to me!